# Location on map of BARESNO in Poland/Russia+1880-1912?

Tags: 19th-century, poland, russia, historical-gazetteer

Where is the town of BARESNO located on a map in Poland/Russia in the time-frame 1880-1912?

Comment: Joan, welcome to Genealogy & Family History StackExchange. I've edited your question to remove your email address as we prefer you to put that in your profile if you choose to do so -- click where it says "Joan Derry" to edit your profile. I've also added some more tags to make it easier for experts to find your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not sure of the spelling, then it could be:

- [Brzeżno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brze%C5%BCno);
- [Brzeźno, (part of Gdańsk)](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Brze%C5%BAno,+Gda%C5%84sk,+Poland/@54.4045793,18.6151421,14z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x46fd0b4b1358baf7:0x584407c5f154828d!8m2!3d54.407593!4d18.6325201); or even
- [Brzuska](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brzuska) (Which used to be part of the Ukraine).